# Not reading an SSD hard drive

Tags: ssd

I had a laptop with Ubuntu and an SSD drive: the laptop had an hardware problem with the screen (never had other issues), and the company gave me back my money and the SSD drive.

Now: I have another PC with Ubuntu which I was using during these weeks, but when I connect the SSD drive it doesn't read it. What should I do? Any pointers? I'm quite sure there is no hardware problem and that the disk is working, I just need to access some files in it.

`sudo parted -l` gives me this (I omit the part about the other HDD that is read):

```
Modello: ATA LITEONIT LCS-128 (scsi)
Disco /dev/sdb: 128GB
Dimensione del settore (logica/fisica): 512B/512B
Tabella delle partizioni: gpt

Numero  Inizio  Fine    Dimensione  File system  Nome  Flag
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB       fat32              avvio
 2      538MB   1050MB  512MB       ext2
 3      1050MB  128GB   127GB                          lvm
```

Comment: You provided too little information, nobody will be able to answer. What filesystem do you have on the SSD?

Comment: Thanks. This is something I get with `sudo fdisk -l`: 

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
Disk /dev/sdb: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 15566 cilindri, totale 250069680 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0xeb1f7225

Comment: `fdisk` has a problem reading GPT partitions.  [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/954246/edit) your question and add the output from `parted -l` command.

Comment: You probably have to install `lvm2` since the sdb disk is in lvm format.

Comment: lvm is something I have not tried, so - I can only pass on that.

Comment: @Hannu What's the point of telling us that you have to "pass on that"... here, and as a comment to your own answer?

Comment: =-) recheck, I moved it. Edited/amended the answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `lvm` and I run **gparted** with

```
sudo gparted
```

then I activated the right partition. Now I see it.